# Programmatically disable NTP?

Tags: windows, rust, ntp

I'm writing a desktop app that changes the system time. In order for this to work I need to disable NTP when the app starts, then enable it again when the app stops.

On linux I can do

```rust
        Command::new("timedatectl")
            .args(["set-ntp","0"])
```

Is there something similar for windows, whether launching an external process or calling a system library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[w32time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/windows-time-service-top) is the Windows time service.

```
net.exe stop w32time

net.exe start w32time
```